# How to make player bounce up and down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a very simple android game but I am new at coding. I want my player to continuously go up and down the screen, but can't make it wordk.

```
public class DuckBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
float speed = 1f;
float verticality;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (transform.position.y < Screen.height -10) {
        velocity.y = 0.7f;
    } else if (transform.position.y > 10) {
        velocity.y = -0.7f;
    }
    transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two issues with the code. The first is that if the gameobject starts on screen as opposed to offscreen then its velocity will remain at Vector2.zero. The second issue is that Screen.height is in pixels but transform is in Unity's units. Hope this helps.

```
public class DuckBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
float speed = 1f;
float verticality;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    velocity.y = 0.7f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //Requires that an orthographic camera named "MainCamera" exists with y transform of 0
    if (transform.position.y < -Camera.main.orthographicSize) {
        velocity.y = 0.7f;
    } else if (transform.position.y > Camera.main.orthographicSize) {
        velocity.y = -0.7f;
    }
    transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (taken from Unity forums - [see here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14279/make-an-object-move-from-point-a-to-point-b-then-b.html). 
Beware, the code is not actually tested :)

```
public class DuckBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

 float speed = 1f;
 float verticality;
 Vector3 pointB;

 IEnumerator Start () {
    Vector3 pointA = transform.position;
    while (true) {
       yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, 3.0));
       yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, 3.0));
    }
  }

 IEnumerator MoveObject (Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time) {
     float i = 0.0f;
     float rate = 1.0f / time;
     while (i < 1.0f) {
         i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
         thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
         yield return null; 
      }
   }

 }
```

C# requires you to use the StartCoroutine method and any methods to be used as coroutines must return IEnumerator. This page explains [how coroutines work](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).